# Why am I getting different values in c++?

Tags: c++, gcc, runtime

I am getting different values for the a variable which is an int.
Although I know I am not initializing it, the value changes from 32767 32766 32765 and 32764  for variable a (with code version 1) and its always 0 with code version 2.
I know I don't have to leave variables uninitialized, just asked this question to see if anybody knew what is happening behind the scenes at runtime, I am using gcc .

**whith code version 1**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 int a;
 int *b = new int; //   <----- this line 
 std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<*b<<std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

**whith code version 2**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 int a;
 std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
 int *b = new int; //    <----- same line moved here  
 std::cout<<*b<<std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You read an uninitialized value => you get undefined behavior. There's nothing interesting happening here.

Comment: if you want it to be 0 you do int* i = new int(); otherwise you get whatever is in that memory location

Comment: ok, thank you. Just don't know why a is ALWAYS 0 if the b variable is created after the first std::cout line.

Comment: that is closer to the answer I am looking for. thanks anyways. I know I shouldn't ask questions like this one.

Comment: @HoNgOuRu Well, although it is undefined behaviour, it's always fun to know what your compiler generates. If you're using linux, try this: `g++ -S -fverbose-asm -o test_asm.s test.cpp` and then `as -alhnd test_asm.s > test.lst`. You'll get the **assembly** code that your compiler generates (maybe it looks complicated, but me and my friends found out the reason of strange pointer-to-constant behaviour with this method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You read uninitialized memory. This is undefined behavior. That means the C++ language rules give literally no guarantee what happens when you run this code, at all. You may see the values you observed, nothing at all, crash your PC or set your house on fire. All equally legal outcomes of running this code.

In practice this will only print unpredictable garbage values in the range of `int` of course, dependent on what just happens to be left over in your memory and do nothing interesting.

Proof from the standard (N4140) for the non-believers:

> When storage for an object
>   with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate value, and if
>   no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is
>   replaced (5.17). [ Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2. —
>   end note ] **If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined** except in the
>   following cases:

[8.5 (12)], emphasize mine, the exceptions following this don't apply.

Comment: Why does reading an uninitialized variable causes UB? Is reading a garbage value considered undefined?

Comment: @InQusitive Yes.

Comment: shouldn't it comes under unspecified behaviour?

Comment: @InQusitive not if the standard declares that it's undefined behavior.  Which it does.

Answer (score 2):

It's an unchecked coincidence in a **highly** complex system.

That may be the best answer you'll get regarding why uninitialized memory in your computer is showing you the pattern you see.

[See also...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect)

Answer (score 0):

The c++ statement `new int` allocates memory from the heap but it doesn't initialize it. So whatever was on the heap or memory from before is being read. You have to do `int *b = new int(0)` to initialize what b is pointing to with 0.

Comment: I was asking about the value of "a". Nevertheless I realized it is a stupid question to ask.

Comment: "a" is an uninitialized stack variable so it will print whatever value is on the stack.